# Getting error while sending email by using Streamsets

Tags: email, jython, streamsets

i am trying to send an email by using StreamSets.

for this, i am using Directory as Source(list of receipts in the text file) and

Jython Evaluator for  Processing and trash for Destination(for testing only).

when i run pipeline, running without any error. but getting error mail to my sender_email like this:

```
Your message wasn't delivered to com.streamsets.pipeline.stage.processor.scripting.ScriptRecord@3ea57368 because the domain 3ea57368 couldn't be found. Check for typos or unnecessary spaces and try again.
```

Here is my sample code:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import logging
for record in records:
  try:
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['Subject'] = 'simple email in python'
    message = 'here is the email'
    msg.attach(MIMEText(message))
    mailserver = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
    mailserver.ehlo()
    mailserver.starttls()
    mailserver.ehlo()
    mailserver.login('sateesh.karuturi9@gmail.com', 'password')
    mailserver.sendmail('sateesh.karuturi9@gmail.com',record,msg.as_string())
    output.write(record)
    mailserver.quit()
  except Exception as e:
    error.write(record, str(e))
```

Here is my error:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You're seeing this because you're using the record object as the email address - `com.streamsets.pipeline.stage.processor.scripting.ScriptRecord@3ea57368` is the string value of a record instance.

If you're using text data format in the Directory origin, then you can use `record.value['text']` instead of `record`:

```
mailserver.sendmail('sateesh.karuturi9@gmail.com', record.value['text'], msg.as_string())
```

If you're using a different data format (delimited, JSON etc), use preview to figure out which field the email address is in, and reference it the same way.